# my bot is sending multiple messages discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot and recently came across a issue, I am making an economy system for my bot and I used some code for a leader board command. the issue is that the bot gets the members with money one by one and send embeds for the first user ,the second and first, the third,sencond and first user, is there anything wrong here.

```
module.exports = {
    name: "leaderboard",
    description: "Check the sever's leaderboard",

    async execute (client, message, args) {
        let money = db.startsWith(`money_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: '.data' })

        let content = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++){
            let user = client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[2]).username

            content += `${i+1}. ${user} - ${money[i].data} \n`;

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${message.guild.name}'s Leaderboard`)
            .setDescription(`${content}`)
            .setColor('#FF4500')
            .setTimestamp()

            message.channel.send(embed);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "leaderboard",
    description: "Check the sever's leaderboard",

    async execute (client, message, args) {
        let money = db.startsWith(`money_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: '.data' })

        let content = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < money.length; i++){
            let user = client.users.cache.get(money[i].ID.split('_')[2]).username

            content += `${i+1}. ${user} - ${money[i].data} \n`;
        }
       const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${message.guild.name}'s Leaderboard`)
            .setDescription(`${content}`)
            .setColor('#FF4500')
            .setTimestamp()

       message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

You simply had the embed and the part where you send the embed inside your for-loop.

A for-loop executes the code inside it, for example 100x. So lets say `money.length` is `2`. It would start at 0 as you say with `let i = 0` and store the found user in `user`. Then it adds the position, the user and the money of this user to the `content` string. After that it would send the embed in your code because it is inside the loop. All that would happen again in the second run of the loop. So it would send two embeds.